# Avoid NAs while intersecting matrix

Tags: r

I have a file as like this

```
Animal Size count
Dog    2.3   25
cat    0.01  36
rat    2.33  45
deer   15.3 
beer   56 
       20.2
```

Then I convert into matrix

```
as.matrix(data)
```

Then I tried to intersect as like this

```
 data[,"count"]
[1] "25" "36" "45" NA   NA   NA
```

How do I remove those NA or How to avoid it ?

Comment: that column has missing data. what do you exactly need? all the non-NA values? most of the answers provided below will work. or like na.omit(data[,"count"]) to remove the NAs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
> data$count
[1] "25" "36" "45" NA   NA   NA  
> data$count[is.na(data$count)] = ""
> data$count
[1] "25" "36" "45" ""   ""   ""
```

Answer (score 1):

or another way:

```
data[,"count"][!is.na(data[,"count"])]
#25 36 45
```